# Howto hide VerticalScrollbar from WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

To avoid any questions: I have autoscrolling HTML content.

I want to hide the vertical scrollbar of my WebView but my first attempt

```
<WebView controlExtensions:WebViewExtensions.HtmlSource="{Binding News.DetailNews.ContentRaw}" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

did not work, the scrollbar is still visible.

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/269510/disable-webview-scrolling-in-windows-store-apps/) the `WebView` doesn't have its own scroll bars. They come from the HTML content.

Comment: Right, so you would have to use HTML/CSS/JavaScript to hide them.

Comment: Yes, that worked for me, thank you ChrisF. Maybe you want to write down a answer, so i can accept it?